# Unity UIElemens changing style.cursor in code

Tags: unity-game-engine

How do I set the cursor style for a VisualElement to one of the predefined classes **in code**? (Arrow, Text, Split Resize Left Down, etc)

I am aware the cursor can be set using the CursorStyle property
`style.cursor = SomeCursorStyle;`

The problem is I want to use the SplitResizeLeftRight cursor and I can't seem to find where the static classes are defined. Obviously I can do this though a stylesheet, but I want to do it through code. An alternative is to create my own CursorStyle and point it to the appropriate cursor textuer, but again, I can't seem to find where those are located.

According to these [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIE-USS-SupportedProperties.html) and the UIElement Debugger I know I can change the style of the cursors. I just can't figure out how to set it to one of those in code.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UIElementsEditorUtility class no longer exists. I found a solution for the more recent version of Unity *(2022.1.7 In my case)* but it includes some C# Reflection...

```
//using System.Reflection;

public static void SetCursor(this VisualElement element, MouseCursor cursor)
{
    object objCursor = new Cursor();
    PropertyInfo fields = typeof(Cursor).GetProperty("defaultCursorId", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    fields.SetValue(objCursor, (int)cursor);
    element.style.cursor = new StyleCursor((Cursor)objCursor);
}
```

I hope it will help those who have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the MouceCursor enum:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MouseCursor.html

> "Custom mouse cursor shapes used with EditorGUIUtility.AddCursorRect."

It defines multiple cursor shapes, one of them is **SplitResizeLeftRight**. Usage example:

```
EditorGUIUtility.AddCursorRect(new Rect(20, 20, 140, 40), MouseCursor.SplitResizeLeftRight);
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: No, this is for the IMGUI I am specifically using UIElements. VisualElements have a CursorStyle property that can be set to change the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

By some miracle I stumbled upon this class: `UIElementsEditorUtility`

At the time of posting the class can not be found in Unity docs.

So here is an example of how to use it:

```
style.cursor = UIElementsEditorUtility.CreateDefaultCursorStyle(MouseCursor.ResizeHorizontal);
```

Comment: good find, thanks bud! gotta love them unity easter eggs lol

Comment: The `UIElementsEditorUtility` class doesn't exist anymore